# executor service with multiple tasks on each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

After researching the web I couldn't find an answer so I hope someone here can.

I'm running an executorservice with multiple threads (lets say 2 for simplification). On each thread I'm submitting a runnable which has many tests in it. Those tests use a software on my computer.

My scenario is that if test fails on any thread - I need to restart the software on my computer.

So if a test on thread one now needs to restart the software - I need to pause the work of the second thread (all threads basically needs pausing including thread one).

On the second thread a test might be using the software - so I want to finish that running test - pause the next tests in line/the thread itself - restart the software - and continue the work on both (all) threads.

Things I've tried and not quite sure how to implement are: all the offers from John from these videos: [Advanced Java: Multi-threading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdlnEWC-7Wo&list=PLBB24CFB073F1048E&index=1).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So you want to shutdownNow() the thread pool when any task fails??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look to [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

You could implement an instance of singleton that will store the status (pause / run) for your software (take care of the concurrency), and for each of your `Runnable` test, you'll check the state at the beginning of the execution. If the State is on hold, then re-schedule the task with a small delay (evaluate the restart time of your software). That means, you should certainly pass the ServiceExecutor a input parameter of the constructor of your task (and store it as variable).

Comment: The OP is already using an ExecutoreService, can you say how using a Scheduled one will make a difference?

Comment: you have to use `schedule` on a task instead of `execute`, in order run a task for the second and following times. This is not possible with any `ExecutorService`.

Comment: I agree you need to use scheduleAt... to have a repeating tasks. I am not sure that's what the OP asked about though.